# Python expression evaluation inside [ ] seems broken

Tags: python

Working with some internally developed tools at work I found some behavior that I can't explain.  I've recreated the problem with a contrived example:

```
>>> _list = [3, 4]
>>> test0 = "string"
>>> test1 = 7
>>> _list[test0 == "string" & test1 == 7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
>>> _list[(test0 == "string") & (test1 == 7)]
4
```

The interpreter appears to be interpreting the & first, instead of the == first.

[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)  states that order of evaluation should be == then &

Is this a bug in the Python interpreter?  I'm using 3.6.3

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the bitwise operator `&`, rather than the boolean logic operator `and`?

Comment: My question isn't how to make it work, it is WHY does without parenthesis evaluate the & first when Python documentation states the precedence is == then &.

Comment: The order of operations page you linked clearly shows that `&` (bitwise and) is a higher precedence than `==`. This example is very questionable, because introducing a list and boolean indexing into the list just obfuscates what you're really asking about.

Comment: You're not really using a list are you? Note that if you are trying to use booleans to slice a list you can only get either the 0 or 1 index values from the list.

Comment: The page you linked to lists them in order from lowest to highest precedence. Maybe that confused you because the analogous documentation for other languages usually goes the other way.

Comment: It's also almost never the case that a 30-year-old industrial-strength programming language with thousands of experienced professionals maintaining has an oversight like this on a primitive operator, or that the docs are wrong. Stop and re-check your assumptions if you find yourself making this assertion.

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy  yep I'm aware.  This syntax/structure was used due to some "interesting" API that was created by some folks

Comment: @ggorlen yea I rechecked my assumptions several times and asked a fellow engineer to do the same.  We both made the same mistake (probably since he saw me make the same mistake)   This syntax is such an odd thing that I figured it was possible so few people had ever used it they hadn't noticed this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [§6.16. Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), `==` has lower precedence than `&`. Confusingly, the table lists operators from lowest to highest precedence. (I had to stare at it for a minute to make sure I was reading it right.)

That means that expression is parsed as:

```
_list[test0 == ("string" & test1) == 7]
```